# Computing P-value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I am doing a lower-tail test and my z-statistic is  -1.57. Now I have to calculate the p-value. My way of finding the p-value using a z-table is: I looked for row -1.5, then look for column 0.07. The entry is 0.0582. Since the test is a lower-tail form, the p-value is 0.0582. But from [this source](http://www.mathcracker.com/solved-problems/statistics/hypothesis_testing_5.php) I found the p-value for the given problem is 0.58051. How was this calculated?

Comment: The significance level is not needed for this question, I removed the somewhat confusing discussion of that part as an unnecessary distraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no other explanation to this, than that those guys from the website made a mistake, seeing $0.58051$ in $0.058051$

Comment: That is , I am correct.